# Where are .NET 4.5 assemblies located?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the .Net Framework 4.5 directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070518/where-is-the-net-framework-4-5-directory)

usually you would find them under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

[image]

But I can't see it after installing Visual Studio 11 (Beta), which also installs .NET 4.5
Where are they located?

Comment: I don't understand. The so called original was asked on Aug 22, 2012. I asked this question back in Mar 03, 2012. How is my question a duplicate?