# Environment.Version returns a version number not matching the "version name"

Tags: .net, version

Upon running this code:

```
foreach (string drive in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())    
    Console.WriteLine("Drive: {0}", drive);

    Console.WriteLine("OS: {0}", Environment.OSVersion);
    Console.WriteLine("Processor count: {0}", Environment.ProcessorCount);
    Console.WriteLine(".NET version: {0}", Environment.Version);
```

I get

[image]

When I downloaded and started the .NET installer, I was told that the 4.5 version was already installed. Is there a difference between the version name, and the actual version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - basically [.NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40), so `Environment.Version` will return the same version number for the first 3 parts. The *build* part of the version number (18010 in your case) is different between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 (and potentially updates to each) but the major/minor/patch level is 4.0.30319 in both cases.

It's confusing as heck, but that's the situation, I'm afraid.

Comment: It was part of a tutorial code sample, not really my code. I just copied and pasted it in here. Thanks.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic: You might want to find a better tutorial ;)

Comment: @Jon_Skeet It seems there was no curly braces in the code and I added them for some reason. The tutorial is not the blame. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic: Makes sense :) Will remove the comment from my answer.

Comment: Environment.Version does not return the .NET Framework version number for the first 3 parts. But it return CLR version.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.5 is a drop-in replacement for 4.0 - the version number is indeed what you see.

Check the versions of the assemblies in the [reference assemblies directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070518/where-is-the-net-framework-4-5-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with .NET Core 3.0 (and .NET Standard 2.1) situation is changed and now `Environment.Version` working properly.

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine($"Environment.Version: {System.Environment.Version}");

// Old result
//   Environment.Version: 4.0.30319.42000
//
// New result
//   Environment.Version: 3.0.0
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#improved-net-core-version-apis) for further information.