# Inno Setup - Run InstallUtil from .Net 4.5 Location

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup provides variables for `{dotnet35}` and `{dotnet40}`, but I need to run the `InstallUtil.exe` program from something like `{dotnet45}`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such constant like `{dotnet45}` defined, however you can use the [`{dotnet40}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#dotnet40) constant, since .NET 4.5 is just an inplace upgrade for .NET 4.0. So, .NET 4.5 is in the same directory as .NET 4.0.

Related questions:

- [Where is the .NET Framework 4.5 directory ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12070518/960757)
- [Where is .NET Framework 4.5 directory located ?](https://superuser.com/q/522027)