# Inno Setup: Constant for latest FrameWork

Tags: frameworks, inno-setup

I would like to know if there is a constant like {dotnet40} that would find the latest installed NET framework on the user's computer, no matter which one that would be?

Something like {dotnethighestavailable}?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such constant `{dotnethighestavailable}`. It would be useless anyway because you need to consider that not always you will have the latest Inno Setup release which would reflect the most recent .NET framework.

If your question has been raised because you are missing a `{dotnet45}` constant, then I would refer you to [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19868354/960757), where is written that .NET 4.5 framework is in the same directory as .NET 4.0 and so you can use the [`{dotnet40}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#dotnet40) constant.