# Is .net framework 4.6 required to compile a c# code in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6

I was just checking which versions of .Net framework installed on my machine and realized the versions 4.5 and 4.6 are not available. However, I can compile a c# project target to framework 4.6 in VS 2015. I want to know is it possible or I am not looking at the right place to see the installed framework on my machine. I am using this [approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) to check installed.Net framework.

Comment: .Net 4.6 will be installed when you install VS2015. It's not optional. Obviously how you're checking whether it's installed or not is wrong.
MSDN [explains how to check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the minimal version of .NET framework is limited by functionality that you use in your code although Microsoft Build Tools 2015 requires at least .NET framework 4.5. Easiest way to check your version is to open "Uninstall program" window in "Control Panel" by the way.

Comment: I can see .net framework 4.6 in "Uninstall program" window. However, I want to locate directory containing .net framework 4.6.

Comment: I have already checked and .net framework 4.5 and 4.6 do not exist there

Comment: I found some (possibly) helpful information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070518/where-is-the-net-framework-4-5-directory)