# How does .Net code run in Azure PaaS?

Tags: c#, azure, paas

Probably I'm missing something obvious here. How does a .net code runs in Azure Cloud Service (PaaS)? From the looks of it, PaaS machine is just a Windows Server with no .Net framework installed (I do not see in the programs and features). Then how does the code run on the cloud? Doesn't it need a CLR?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: .net cannot run without clr/mono...so it is installed. you cannot find it in programs, but it should be in features.

Comment: Did that machine had a .NET solution of a cloud service deployed when you  took that screen shot?

Comment: This isn't specific to azure, but to the .net framework on windows.... As others have said, the .net framework does not appear in *programs*, it appears in ***features***.   use the option "Turn Windows features on or off", and look under the IIS node.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cloud Service has .Net Framework. I think you might misread that it does not have .Net Framework **3.5**. But you can install it while deploying your package: [howto](http://anuchandy.blogspot.kr/2014/06/automating-net-35-installation-on-azure.html).

In the architecture point of view, each Azure Cloud Service machine is Windows Server so you can login with Remote Desktop Protocol(RDP) at Visual Studio > Server Explorer pane. At there, you can see IIS which hosts your WebRole.

**+ Append**

You can see .Net Framework installed at `D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`. And refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38333493/361100), I can see my WebRole has `379893` (.NET Framework 4.5.2) installed.

Comment: Yeah, it should be having a .net framework installed. But what's bugging me is I don't find it in the installed programs and features. See picture attached to my question

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal // I appended detailed answer. HTH.

Comment: Note: Web / Worker role instances are not *subsets* of Windows Server; Each instance *is* Windows Server.

Comment: @DavidMakogon // thanks for letting me know. I updated answer.