# .NET 4.8 says already installed but it isnt

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to download .NET framework 4.8 but it said already installed, i checked my framework file and the latest version there is 4.0.30319 which supports only upto c# version 5 but i need to use version 8. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: Look here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool/

Comment: Try check file location, may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070518/where-is-the-net-framework-4-5-directory

Comment: I think what is happening is the Net Version 4.0 cannot get uninstalled.  So repairing 4.0 will allow 4.8 to get installed.

Comment: @ValeriuSeremet i dont think that the 4.0.30319 one is 4.8 because things like Console.WriteLine($"Hello {variable}") give the error unexpected '$' which means its being compiled as an older version

Comment: I just realised that it did install but there is another problem,  (i cant do new post because 90minute cooldown) When i try to compile this is what cmd says:

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3752.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240