# Azure App Service and .Net Framework versions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Asp.Net Web API set to target .NET 4.6.1 which is published to an Azure App Service.

I received a [notification](https://github.com/jeffwmartinez/appservicedotnetframework.github.io#net-framework-48-is-coming-to-app-service) from Microsoft about the imminent move to .NET 4.8 for Azure App Service.

The notification recommends I test my applications locally.

I can see that v4.6.1 is an installed version of .NET framework for my Azure App Service:

[image]

Two questions:

1. Given v4.6.1 exists will my Web API continue to use v4.6.1 regardless of the later versions of .NET framework that are present?
2. What (if any) testing is needed prior to the v4.8 App Service Update? Is it just a case of building it locally using v4.8 to confirm it builds/runs, or is a thorough batch of regression testing warranted?

Comment: Your screen shot is about a completely different thing, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-referenced-assemblies-7d752d92c18c

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the screenshot is about a 'completely different thing'? From reading your blog post I understand that the screenshot above confirms that the latest in-place version of .Net Framework on my Azure app service is currently v4.7.2. Is that correct?

Comment: Referenced assemblies are merely references. That screen shot proves nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Given v4.6.1 exists" is not a valid assumption. What you saw is merely the referenced assemblies installed on your local machine for development. Even if your code is compiled against v4.6.1 referenced assemblies, at runtime it is executed by the actual runtime version (v4.6.1 or above), so the actual behaviors are controlled by that runtime.
2. That's another subjective thing. Most enterprises will choose a thorough batch of regression testing, though individual developers might choose to simply compile/run.

Comment: So there is a single .Net framework runtime for the App Service which will in most situations be the latest of the referenced assemblies present, in the case above this is v4.7.2? And although my code is built against v4.6.1 when it is running in the App Service we are relying on the backward compatibility between v4.7.2 and v4.6.1 for it to run without issue?

Comment: This post answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070518/where-is-the-net-framework-4-5-directory